# Estimating the date when a web page was first published on the Internet

Tags: web, url, caching, web-crawler

As a part of an academic research project, I would like to know the date UberEats launched in each city ([here is the link](https://www.ubereats.com/gb/location) to all cities/towns UberEats covers). I can find this information for large cities by crawling the news, but for many smaller towns, there's no mention of the date Ubereats lunches in those cities in the news.

To get around this issue, I came up with the idea that I might be able to estimate the entry date of UberEats in the city by looking at the date that the corresponding web page for that city was created on the UberEats website. I tried the look at the date the web page was indexed in google, but that didn't work. I then tried to dig into the HTML source of the webpage. However, so far, I have not been able to extract this information from the webpage source.

I need someone to advise me on how I can get an estimation of the date when a page, like one of the following, was first published on the web.

https://www.ubereats.com/gb/city/manchester-eng/

https://www.ubereats.com/gb/store/starbucks-manchester-deansgate/yXWK5pZIR9al9z8Zc7wRJg

To be clear, these two web pages are examples. I would like to know generally how I can get this information for similar web pages.

Best,

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this website](https://carbondate.cs.odu.edu) to **estimate** when the site was published. Here is the result for your first example:

> Estimated creation date: 2020-09-21T17:25:20

That said, an exact date is not possible for a website path unless the website provides that information. You can find the exact date a base path was published using other tools.

Comment: Thanks. But it seems it fetches the information from web.archive.org, which is not close to the actual publication date (I have cross-checked this info for the subset of cities that I know the exact publication date from the official news)

Comment: I added onto my response to fully answer the question.